# Odds of winning meg millions

Tags: probability

The [official site](http://www.megamillions.com/howto/) says the chances of winning the jackpot is 1 in 175,711,536, when I do the math, I get a different number. Can someone correct me please

```
5 balls out of lot of 56 
1 ball out of a lot of 46

Total possible combination:

56 x 55 x 54 x 53 x 52 x 46 = 21,085,384,320
```

### **Edit :**

I am going to add this

The odds of winning a $2 ticket is listed as 1/75 on the megamillion site. Shouldn't that be 1/46.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference is that you are counting every possible *permutation* rather than every possible *combination*.  For instance, the sequence $10,20,30,40,50$  is equivalent to $50,40,30,20,10.$  Since you have $5!$ equivalent permutation for each combination (given there are 5 numbers picked out of the big lot), you need to divide your result by $120$: giving the published odds of $1:175,711,536$.

As for your followup question, I just checked the game's rules and you win that prize *iff* you have the bonus number *and none of the primaries*.

The general equation you are looking for is the number of permutations of *m* balls picked out of *n*:

$\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$

Getting none of the primary balls means getting a combination of all the numbers *except* those you picked (51!/46!) divided by all the possible combinations (56!/51!).  So the odds of having none of the primary numbers is (very close to) 61% - the odds of that *and* having the bonus ball give a bit over 1:75 odds of winning that $2

Comment: Ok i forgot about combinatios vs computation. But the chances of winning $2 is said to be 1/75. Shoudn't that be 1/46. AS the only ball matters is the last ball and chances of that is 1/46.

Comment: It should, I expect, but I'm not familiar with the game's rules so I could not tell you what other factors might be taken into account.

For instance, do you win that lot *only* if you have no other correct ball (which would reduce the odds), or some other factor like this?

Comment: yes if the last ball match, the first 5 does not matter. You win $2. The last ball is picked out of 46 balls.

Comment: @TomCat The others do matter at least a little. For example, if the others are all correct you will win the jackpot rather than $2.

Comment: you are going to ge the other numbers in any case. The probability of winning just a 2$ ticket using the megamillion ball should be 1/46 as it picked of a lot of 46 balls.

Comment: @TomCat check the official site you linked to; you win that prize at 1:75 odds if you get "0+1", that is _no_ normal balls and the megamillion ball.  (If you got the megamillion balls and some normal balls you get _different_ prizes, at stated odds).

Comment: It's closer to 61.5% to get none of the primaries: 27965/45474. That gives the chance to get no primaries plus the bonus as very nearly 1:74.8.